# object detection javascript - How to draw detection boundries on video

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, html5-video, object-detection

I have html video tag with recording, and array of json objects with detections of people in every frame.

when i play the video ,i'm already drawing the boxes with html and css by setInterval function, but the boxes aren't fit the position of the people in the video although the detections seems correct.
is there more exact way to put the boxes on the video?
Here is a sample json:
[image]

Comment: how did you get the detection, where are the x,y offset from? is the scale of the video on the page matching the scale of the coordinates? if the timestamp of the coordinates matching the displayed timestamp?

Comment: Could you please put your code in a snippet on http://www.codepen.io ? It will be easier to help